# How to replace / for \/ in R?

Tags: html, r, json

I need a code to parse a html file to json in R for a REST call. Since i was unable to find any parser that worked for my ends, i was doing it myself.
For some reason i am unable to transform `"/"` into `"\/"`

```
s = "https://test.app.net/pixel"
```

to

```
"https:\/\/test.app.net\/pixel"
```

Some attempts were

```
s = gsub("/","\\/",s)
s = gsub("/","\\\\/",s)
s = gsub("/","\/",s,fixed = TRUE)
```

The results showed exactly the same string or double backslash instead of a single one.

Edit:
After reading @MrFlick response i was able to solve my issue

```
html = gsub("/","sa\\\\/",html)
html = gsub("sa\\\\",'\\\\',html)
```

was enough to create the desired effect since R would interpret it twice, but it was only visible using cat().
after a lot of hours doing the html to json parse i learnt that toJson(), if properly used could do exactly what i needed from the beginning...

Comment: Why do you want backslashes in your URL? I don't know if any R tools automatically fix them back to forward-slashes (though I haven't done extensive testing, just `httr::GET`).

Comment: For instance, you should be able to url-encode it with `URLencode(s,reserved=TRUE)`, which produces a string that unambiguous decodes to the original without manual string substitution.

Comment: Note that when R prints string values to the console it will by default escape certain sequences. This may make it unclear what is actually contained in the string. If you call `cat()` on the value rather than the default `print()` it will show the value without escapes. You can see how `cat("https:\\/\\/test.app.net\\/pixel")` looks different than `print("https:\\/\\/test.app.net\\/pixel")`

Comment: @r2evans I need to dinamically send a html file to a service provider using their API, which means i have to parse a html file to JSON. For this a need some characters to be escaped such as "/" to "\/". A json parser tool would solve my issues, but as far as i know theres no such tool in R.